# How do you use python to create an object that represents a month and can be looped over?

Tags: python, datetime

What I am trying to do is allow the user to input a month, then create an object representing that month, and then loop over the object day by day starting with the first day of the month. If the day is Monday do `x` is the day is Tuesday do `y`

So far I have tried using the `datetime module`. I can figure out a way to put in a start and stop date, but not to create a month that I can handle the way I want to from a single piece of user input.

If anyone knows of a way this could be done with either datetime or another module I would be greatful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`dateutil.rrule`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/rrule.html) is pretty much exactly what you need. The interface is a bit odd as the source material and primary use case is [icalendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar)'s recurrence rules and dateutil follows that terminology, but beyond that it should trivially handle your use-case.

Comment: Played with this module after and got it to do what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using datetime and timedelta - adding days to a starting day:

```
import datetime

# 0 == Monday, 1== Tuesday .... the list is the list of lessons taught on that day
teach = {0: ["A","B"], 1:["C","D"],2:["E"],3:["A","E"], 4:["E","B","E"]}

# get a starting month
while True:
    try:
        month = int(input("Month [1-12]: "))
    except:
        continue

    if 1 <= month <= 12:
        break

# date to start at
start = datetime.datetime(2019,month,1)

# create all days of that month 
m = [[date, teach.get(date.weekday())]    # date  + lessons
     for date in (start + datetime.timedelta(days=n) for n in range(32))  # all days
     if date.month == month]  # only those that fit into the month

print()
for day in m:
    print(day)
```

Output:

```
Month [1-12]: 4
[datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 1, 0, 0), ['A', 'B']]
[datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 2, 0, 0), ['C', 'D']]
[datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 3, 0, 0), ['E']]
[datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 4, 0, 0), ['A', 'E']]
[datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 5, 0, 0), ['E', 'B', 'E']]
[datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 6, 0, 0), None]
[datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 7, 0, 0), None]
[datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 8, 0, 0), ['A', 'B']]
[datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 9, 0, 0), ['C', 'D']]
[datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 10, 0, 0), ['E']]
[datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 11, 0, 0), ['A', 'E']]
[datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 12, 0, 0), ['E', 'B', 'E']]
[datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 13, 0, 0), None]
[datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 14, 0, 0), None]
[datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 15, 0, 0), ['A', 'B']]
[datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 16, 0, 0), ['C', 'D']]
[datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 17, 0, 0), ['E']]
[datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 18, 0, 0), ['A', 'E']]
[datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 19, 0, 0), ['E', 'B', 'E']]
[datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 20, 0, 0), None]
[datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 21, 0, 0), None]
[datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 22, 0, 0), ['A', 'B']]
[datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 23, 0, 0), ['C', 'D']]
[datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 24, 0, 0), ['E']]
[datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 25, 0, 0), ['A', 'E']]
[datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 26, 0, 0), ['E', 'B', 'E']]
[datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 27, 0, 0), None]
[datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 28, 0, 0), None]
[datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 29, 0, 0), ['A', 'B']]
[datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 30, 0, 0), ['C', 'D']]
```

Doku:

- [datetime.date.weekday()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.weekday)
- [datetime.timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)
- [Why dict.get(key) instead of dict[key]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041405/why-dict-getkey-instead-of-dictkey)
- [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

You would have to remove days that fall on special date where your school is closed - this only looks at the weekday.